# Application.Current.MainPage working inside OnAppearing but not on Button Click

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am facing this weird issue with Xamarin Forms.

This code is working:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
 base.OnAppearing();
 Application.Current.MainPage = new MasterIndexPage();
}
```

but this is not working:

```
private void BtnLogin_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Application.Current.MainPage = new MasterIndexPage();
}
```

Both methods belong to the same view page. I added a break-point inside button click event, which is hitting successfully. But MasterIndexPage is not appearing, view stays on same page.

And there is one more thing... the above behavior is only when I install the app for the first time. If I close and relaunch the app, both the above codes work. There may be something really small, but I am struggling from over 4 hours and still unable to figure out.

Please help.

**Update: Sharing full code sample to reproduce the issue.**

MasterIndexPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                  Title="Workman"
                  x:Class="Workman.MasterIndexPage">

    <MasterDetailPage.Master>

        <ContentPage Title="Menu" BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF">
            <Label Text="Test Menu" />
        </ContentPage>

    </MasterDetailPage.Master>

    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <ContentPage Title="Content" BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF">
            <Label Text="Content Area" />
        </ContentPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>

</MasterDetailPage>
```

MasterIndexPage.xaml.cs

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Workman
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MasterIndexPage : MasterDetailPage
    {

        public MasterIndexPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();            
        }

    }
}
```

LoginPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             Title="About"
             x:Class="Workman.LoginPage">

    <ContentPage.Content>

        <StackLayout Margin="20,20,20,20">

            <Button Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="1" 
                    x:Name="btnlogin" Clicked="BtnLogin_Clicked"
                    TextColor="White" FontSize="Large"
                    Text="Login" />

        </StackLayout>


    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

LoginPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Workman
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
    {

        public LoginPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
        }

        private void BtnLogin_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Current.MainPage = new MasterIndexPage();
            //This line is hitting but not working
        }

    }
}
```

I am able to reproduce the issue with two newly created pages and with above minimalist code. However, as mentioned before, the issue happens only when the app is not installed, on first run. After closing and relaunching, it works.

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue . You could share your sample so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Added

Comment: It works on my side . What is the version of Xamarin.Forms in your project and the test device ?

Comment: You could delete the folder bin and obj , then clean and rebuild your project .

Comment: I already tried deleting the obj and bin on both PCL and Android project before posting this question but that didn't work out. The Xamarin.Forms version I am using is 4.6.0.800.  I also think this is related to some environment issue because this is very basic and should work.

Comment: Does it work now ?

Comment: Thanks for asking Lucas. No. it didn't work out. I have implemented a separate page for app initialization that will run the first time the app is installed and will prompt user that 'Setup is complete. Please restart the application'. Then on second run, navigation works. I know it is not an ideal solution, but works for now, until I figure out what is going on.

Comment: Done. I will also continue to look and will post if I find anything.

Comment: Great ! Thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine on my side . And since it works after you relaunching it, I don't think the issue is caused by your code .

As a better design , you could set the `MainPage` as `MasterIndexPage`  directly in App.xaml.cs . And login page could come as a modal page .

```
public partial class MasterIndexPage : MasterDetailPage
{
    bool HasLogin;


    public MasterIndexPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        if(!HasLogin)
        {
            HasLogin = true;  //  here just for demo , you could change it when user login scuuess
            Navigation.PushModalAsync(new LoginPage());

        }

    }


}
```

#### And in login page

```
private  void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // when login success
        Navigation.PopModalAsync();

    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for doing this Lucas. It may be a workaround but doesn't solve the problem at hand. What will happen if the user clicks 'Back' without attempting login? The UI will fall back to master page. Then I will have to check again if HasLogin is true. So there will be an infinite loop.

Comment: My code is just a demo . You could modify the logic as you need  .

Comment: I am sorry. Really frustrated today! :(

Comment: I will try my best to help you . This is not a serious issue , which has  a workaround .